# XPS Docking DL-6000 upgrade

Tags: drivers, 20.04, dell, xps, docking

I'm currently working on an XPS 13" with Ubuntu 20.04. I have for 2/3 years an WD-15 dock in my house and everything work fine, but my client only have DL-6000 one at the office.

With this (the DL-6000 one), the screen display don't work and I found this : https://gist.github.com/noahp/723832ab8d06770bf6f159c573a65934

My question is : I'm affraid of doing this upgrade (or driver install) because I don't want to break my previous setup. Can someone tell me if my previous dock (and currently home dock) WD-15 will continue to work or is this upgrade will "replace" and make mine obsolete ?

Thank you for taking the time to read this !

Answer (score 1):

I'm you from the futur.

Yes you can, I just did a "F*$k it, i'm testing that" and it seems to not destroy the previous driver. The old dock work, and guess what, the new one too !

You can do that for sure, hope it will help you, trust me man.

And by the way, keep being a great human being, I know that you ARE great.